# Gitlab: How to call child pipelines of different project from different upstream projects with artifacts

Tags: gitlab

I have a requirement to call child pipeline from different upstream projects by also passing artifacts from upstream pipelines. Example:

project A --> .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
 build
 test

build
 stage: build
 script:
 - touch artifactA.txt
 artifacts:
  paths:
 - artifactA.txt

test
 stage: test
 # do something here to call child pipeline residing in different project which tests artifacts from build job
```

project B --> .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
 build
 test

build
 stage: build
 script:
 - touch artifactB.txt
 artifacts:
  paths:
 - artifactB.txt

test
 stage: test
 # do something here to call child pipeline residing in different project which tests artifacts from build job
```

project C --> .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
 test

test
 stage: test
 # do something here which accepts artifacts from upstream pipeline when triggered and runs tests against it.
   needs:
    - project: specify list of upstream projects here which can trigger this pipeline
      ref: integration-test-pipeline
      job: build
      artifacts: true
```

Tried few different ways by referring to gitlab docs by using `needs` , `trigger`, `dependencies` keywords and their variations but nothing worked so far.